# How to regex extract only numbers up to the first comma or after a specific keyword?

Tags: regex, re2

I'm having trouble trying to [regex extract](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract) the 'positions' from the following types of strings:

```text
6 red players position 5, button 2
earn $50 pos3, up to $1,000
earn $50 pos 2, up to $500
table button 4, before Jan 21
```

I want to get the number that comes after 'pos' or 'position', and if there's no such keyword, get the last number before the first comma. The position value can be a number between 1 and 100. So 'position' for each of the previous rows would be:

| Input text | Desired match (position) |
| --- | --- |
| 6 red players position 5, button 2 | 5 |
| earn $50 pos3, up to $1,000 | 3 |
| earn $50 pos 2, up to $500 | 2 |
| table button 4, before Jan 21 | 4 |

I have a big data set (in BigQuery) populated with basically those 4 types of strings.

I've already searched for this type of problem but found no solution or point to start from.

- I've tried `.+?(?=,)` ([link](https://regex101.com/r/fvTMlw/1/)) which extracts everything up to the first comma (`,`), but then I'm not sure how to go about extracting only the numbers from this.
- I've tried `(?:position|pos)\s?(\d)` ([link](https://regex101.com/r/8Vo0lc/1/)) which extracts what I want for group 1 (by using [non-capturing groups](https://dev.to/oluwabukunmige/how-to-capture-more-than-group-when-using-bigquery-regex-4jm3)), but doesn't solve the 4th type of string.

I feel like there's a way to combine these two, but I just don't know how to get there yet.

And so, after the two things I've tried, I have two questions:

1. Is this possible with only regex? If so, how?
2. What would I need to do in SQL to make my life easier at getting these values?

I'd appreciate the help/guidance with this. Thanks a ton!

Comment: So `pos(?:ition)? ?\d+|\d+(?=,)`?

Comment: All of your input text suffices for "get the last number before the comma" so `\d+(?=,)` should work.

Comment: Hmm yeah @MonkeyZeus , you are right. I forgot to specify that it has to be before the 'first' comma. The last one you mentioned also matches the 1 in $1,000. https://regex101.com/r/tALXls/1 I'll give it a try in Big Query though, maybe I can make it work! It's genius

Comment: I don't think you understood my comment. Your "pos|position" requirement is just smoke and mirrors because all of your sample input meet this criteria "get the last number before the first comma". See https://regex101.com/r/PDq88Q/1/ and your desired text is in capture group $1

Comment: Oh that's awesome! Thanks a ton. I honestly don't understand what's going on within `^[^,]*(\d+)(?=,)`, but it kinda works. Do you know why it doesn't match more than 1 digit? For example: https://regex101.com/r/vTj7q1/1 The positions do change from 1 to 100.

Comment: Did you try `^[^,]*(\d+)(?=,)`  Google BigQuery? It uses RE2 and does not support lookarounds. Try switching to Go regex option at regex101.com to see what patterns will work. Try `^(?:[^,]*[^0-9,])?(\d+),`

Comment: Also, "why it doesn't match more than 1 digit" - [here is the answer](https://youtu.be/XDWK_tK2LUE?t=179).

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew ! I thought RE2 referenced PCRE2 (ending in RE2). All these flavors of regex confuse me greatly, so that's why I went with that one. Didn't know it was Golang. That option is straightforward. The video is also very helpful, thanks for that.

Comment: Glad to help, I also posted my solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
^(?:[^,]*[^0-9,])?(\d+),
```

See the [RE2 regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2KyOAw/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[^,]*[^0-9,])?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `[^,]*` - zero or more chars other than comma
  - `[^0-9,]` - a char other than a digit and comma
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `,` - a comma

Comment: @fillipvt If you wonder why I made the `(?:[^,]*[^0-9,])?` optional: it will also allow matching the number at the start of string. That is why I did not use `^[^,]*[^0-9,](\d+),` nor `^[^,]*[^\d,](\d+),`.

Comment: That's awesome, thanks. Also, your YT channel is great! (the one shared above). Each video is very concise and explains very well the concepts. I'll be watching all the vids.

Answer (score 0):

Use look ahead for a comma, with a look behind requiring the previous char to be a space or a letter to prevent matching the “1” in “$1,000”:

```
(?<=[ a-z])(\d+)(?=,)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/COhfSNeitZfq68).

Comment: Sadly, `re2` doesn't support lookarounds